# Azure Monitor Alert for Windows Services

Tags: azure, monitoring, windows-service, alerts

Is it possible to add an Azure Monitor Alert for Windows Services running on Cloud Services?

We have a web app running on Cloud Services depending on a service we installed on the instance VM, we need to be notified when the service stops.

We used to monitor these type of events using WhatsUp, but not sure what is the best way to handle it on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You can put logs from a classic VM but you have to install the Azure Monitor agent on that VM and configure it with your Log analytics namespace.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/quick-collect-windows-computer